# Select data between 2 Date in sql and linq

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql, sql-query-store

hi i need to select some data between 2 date i can do this easily with sql query like this :
`SELECT * FROM  tbl_Check
WHERE
StudentId = 9
AND
CheckDate >= 2010
AND
CheckDate <= 2017`

Note: CheckDate type in Sql Table is: NVARCHAR(12)

now i want use this query in linq i wrote this one but i get error that operator >= cant applied to operand of type string and string.

```
from val in dc.CheckVs
            where val.StudentId == 9 &&
                  val.CheckDate >= txtDate1.Text &&
                  val.CheckDate <= txtDate2.Text
                  select val;
```

Comment: Unless you have a very good reason to do so you shouldn't store dates as strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you field is `NVARCHAR(12)` but the value only is `YEAR` you can convert the columns in `INT`.

Try that.

```
from val in dc.CheckVs
where val.StudentId == 9 &&
      Convert.ToInt32(val.CheckDate.Tostring()) >= Convert.ToInt32(txtDate1.Text) &&
      Convert.ToInt32(val.CheckDate.Tostring()) <= Convert.ToInt32(txtDate2.Text)
select val;
```

I wait this help you ;)

Answer (score 1):

you might require to convert into date and use year() function to check this as below:

```
SELECT * FROM  tbl_Check
  WHERE StudentId = 9
  AND year(convert(date,CheckDate)) >= 2010
  AND year(convert(date,CheckDate)) <= 2017
```

Comment: how about this date?  2017/12/18 i used your code now it give me error that time must be yyyy/MM/dd  hh:mm:ss , but my date dosnt have time.

Comment: SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.'

Comment: Yes valid date range is that https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it this way

```
SELECT * FROM  tbl_Check
  WHERE StudentId = 9
  AND (YEAR(CheckDate) BETWEEN 2010 AND 2017)
```